# Batch File to Remove Files from C:\Users folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I work in a domain environment where devices store local user profiles in the C:\Users folder.

I would like to develop a batch files for users to be able to run to remove files (user profiles) that have not been modified in 90 days. I do need an exemption for any file that ends in .OA or .SA

I had this, but it was started to look in C:\Users\All Users however, that is not one of the directories available to delete.

```
ForFiles /p "C:\Users" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *N. B.:* `forfiles` iterates both files and directories, so you need to exclude the latter: `forfiles /S /P "%PUBLIC%\.." /D -90 /C "cmd /D /C if @isdir==FALSE del @path"`…

Comment: So, if a user does not add or remove any favourites in his web browser in 90 days, they will all be deleted. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to post this single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) as a potential solution for isolating the active user accounts you wish. However I will add, that whilst I have used an improved version of your intended `ForFiles` command, I do not advise that you use it in a real environment. I say that because, depending upon the age of the user account, there will very likely be a great many files within those directory trees, which are needed. Just because a file has not modified, within a certain timespan, it does not mean that it can be deleted. For that reason I have used `Echo @Path` at the end of the command line, instead of your submitted `Del @File`. If you are happy to delete everything which is returned from my code above, feel free to make your deletion replacement.

```sh
@For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where "AccountType = 512 And LocalAccount = 'TRUE' And SIDType = 1 And Status = 'OK'" Assoc:List /ResultClass:"Win32_SID" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "__R"') Do @For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_UserProfile Where "LocalPath Like '%SystemDrive%\\Users\\%%' And SID = '%%G' And Special = 'FALSE'" Get LocalPath /Format:"MOF" 2^>NUL') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "%%H" /S /D -90 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"If @IsDir == FALSE If /I Not @Ext == \"OA\" If /I Not @Ext == \"SA\" Echo @Path\""
```